# How can I link the back-end and the front-end using environment variables in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services in two different containers, and I want to link them using the back-end hostname as an environment variable in the front, how can I do that without changing the variable value manually.

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    ...
    # back-end configuration
  frontend:
    ...
    # front-end configuration
    depends_on:
      - backend
    # docker compose creates docker network and connects all services to it
    # you can connect to other services within this network using service name as hostname
    # in this case to connect to backend just use it's name "backend"
    # below couple examples of how you could define environments to connect to back-end
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOSTNAME=backend
      - BACKEND_URL=http://backend
      - BACKEND_URL_WITH_PORT=http://backend:1234
```

Comment: When I do that the environment variable doesn't get the host name it gets the literal value, for example BACKEND_HOSTNAME value is "backend" and the front fails to load the resources.

Comment: Did you test it locally first? I mean communication between your frontemd and backend?

Comment: I did, with BACKEND_HOSTNAME = localhost, and it worked, I did the same thing on an application server and it worked when I launch the back_end first and then copy its HOSTNAME, but I don't want to do it this way, So I'm wondering if there is a way to automate it.

Comment: Literal value `backend` is exactly what I meant! When you start frontend and backend on localhost, then you can communicate between 2 services using hostname `localhost` but it is also just a literal value which usually points to 127.0.0.1 Now docker-compose creates network and links services with aliases defaulting to service names. So in case from my example frontend service can reach backend using it's service name literally `backend`. Note that this communication will work only within docker-compose setup, to communicate with services from outside you need to expose ports.

Comment: I got your point, But it's still not working, I think 'backend' is not interpreted as a hostname, the same problem might occurs with 'localhost' when it's not defined as a hostname.

Comment: Well you need to configure your application to send requests to proper host, so you must pass somewhere in your app config the hostname, in this case `backend`. How you configure your application is a whole other story which to my understanding was not a point of this question. I'm working with `docker-compose` and I am 100% that services can communicate using their name as hostname within docker-compose network without any additional configuration.

Comment: I didn't mention the app here because, as I said before, when I put the complete URL instead of backend it works, and the app is configured to get the hostname from the os environment variables, so I don't think the problem here is in the app.

Comment: What do you mean by complete url?

Comment: I mean something like www.url.com or locally localhost:ip_address

Comment: You mean `localhost:port`?

Comment: yeah exactly  localhost:port

Comment: So if you configured properly your docker compose then you should just use `backend:port` instead of `localhost:port`.